# Push to observable in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have Observable array which is `similarIdeasObservable: Observable<SimilarIdea[]>;` and containing 10 rows and binded to html

`<article class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let similarIdea of (similarIdeasObservable | async)">`

Now I want to push further 10 rows into `similarIdeasObservable: Observable<SimilarIdea[]>;` by using the following method

```
  onScrollDown(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    if (this.idea !== null) {
      this.loading = true;
      concat(this.similarIdeasObservable, this.ideaService.getSimilarIdeas(this.idea).pipe(
        concatMap(i => i),
        toArray(),
        catchError(error => {
          this.loading = false;
          return throwError(error);
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        })
      )).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
```

First 10 ideas are loaded the following code

```
this.similarIdeasObservable = this.ideaService.getSimilarIdeas(idea).pipe(
            concatMap(i => i),
            startWith(idea.toSimilarIdea()),
            toArray(),
            catchError(error => {
              this.loading = false;
              return throwError(error);
            }),
            finalize( () => {
              this.loading = false;
            })
          );
```

The above method did not work. Could you solve the problem that how can I push into Observable next time?

Comment: what's your rxjs verison?

Comment: @AkshayRana, "rxjs": "~6.4.0",

Comment: try concat(obs1, obs2)
That's how it is in the docs. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

Comment: might be easier to store and push to the actual array `SimilarIdea[]` instead of `Observable<SimilarIdea[]>` :)

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to use parentheses with a pipe. `let similarIdea of similarIdeasObservable | async`

Comment: Can you please update the question to show how the first observable is assigned to `similarIdeasObservable`? How is it assigned an observable?

Comment: what does `getSimilarIdeas` return ? array of observables ?

Comment: both are observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `combineLatest` operator in `onScrollDown()` function instead:

[A working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6dmtpf) for you:

```
this.similarIdeasObservable = combineLatest(this.similarIdeasObservable,this.ideaService.getSimilarIdeas(this.idea).pipe(...))
        //Merge 2 array returned from two above Observables
        .pipe(map(([first$, second$]) => [...first$, ...second$ ]) 

this.similarIdeasObservable.subscribe(data => {console.log(data);});
```

But i notice there might be performance issue if your `onScroll()` is call several times in your app, you should unsubscribe to previous subscribe when it is called again:

```
onScrollDown(): void {
 if(this.scrollDownSubscriptions) {
    this.scrollDownSubscription.unsubscribe();
 }
 ........
 this.scrollDownSubscription = this.similarIdeasObservable.subscribe( ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For rxjs 6+ version,

concat works like :

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';
concat(observable1, observable2, observable3 ...);
```

It should be like:

```
concat(
    this.similarIdeasObservable,
    this.ideaService.getSimilarIdeas(this.idea).pipe(...)
)
```

Reference: [Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html)